# How to extract id from a string in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

`http://www.somewhere.com/0123456789.html`

How to extract the 01234567879 from the string?

Comment: Do you already have the string or you want to extract it from current document's URL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Some Tutorial](http://www.learn-javascript-tutorial.com/RegularExpressions.cfm) might help you getting behind RegExp. Some [RegExp Tester](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html) might help you testing your regular expressions.

aside from that, you're probably looking for

```
var string = "http://www.somewhere.com/0123456789.html",
    id = string.match(/\/(\d+)\.html/)[1];
alert(id);
```

Comment: +1 The only answer that doesn't fail on different domain names, etc.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it.

```
var string = "http://www.somewhere.com/0123456789.html";
string.replace(/^.*\/(.*)\.html$/, "$1");
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this:

```
"http://www.somewhere.com/0123456789.html".match(/\/(\d+)\./)[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var path = document.location.path;
var id = path.replace('.html', '');
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply:

```
var str = "http://www.somewhere.com/0123456789.html";  
var result = /\d+/.exec(str);
```

Result:

```
0123456789
```

Comment: Why the down vote? Anyone cares to test the posted code first ?